# Batching in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, batching

Is it mandatory that all the messages in a Kafka batch should go to the same partition?

Or is it possible to batch up messages (which are supposed to go to different partitions) together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the producer's partition assignment algorithm.
The default is RoundRobin so it will be split equally between the partitions.

You can pass a key for every record in the batch and then a default hash function will be executed for each key and the broker will put the record in the partition returned from the hash function.

You can also override the hash function and write one yourself.

Otherwise, if your Kafka client supports you can pass for each record the partition explicitly.

But you don't have to group messages by partition - only by topic.

Comment: Yes. So actually I am using "sarama" (go library) to send messages. I am passing a key with each message and hence partition is decided based on the hash on the key. Now I was wondering, if I should only batch up messages which are supposed to go to the same partition.
Like is it mandatory on the kafka side that I must batch up messages which are supposed to go to the same partition or can I simply batch up messages without caring about that.

(In my use case, I need to send messages to specific partitions based on a part of the message content, which basically I am setting as the key)

Comment: No. it's not a must at all. Batch up all messages you have for a topic without wondering about the partitions, Kafka handles it correctly.